# Implement '=' method together with method_missing

Tags: ruby, overloading

I've a module `Settings` like the following:

```
module Settings
  extend self

  @_settings = {user: "user1"} #@_seetings would normally be filled with different (dynamic) options
  attr_reader :_settings

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    @_settings.has_key?(name.to_sym) ? @_settings[name.to_sym] :
      raise(NoMethodError, "unknown configuration root #{name}", caller)
  end
end
```

In my application I can use `Settings.user` to access the option `user`

Now I would like to do something like this `Settings.user = "some_user"`

I've tried to add this:

```
def method_missing=(name, *args, &block)
  #some code to assign the value
end
```

Unfortunately this is not working. (`unknown configuration root user= (NoMethodError)`). What is the 'right' way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method name of `something=` referring to a nonexistent method will still be caught by `method_missing`.

You might want to modify `method_missing` to see if the name ends with '=' and behave accordingly.

That said, if you say `Settings.method_name`, then you are calling a method on the `Settings` *module*, and not the instance that includes that module.

Also, modules do not contain state; this is one of the things that distinguishes them from classes.  Also, are you sure you would want to override a `method_missing` method of the including class (or have it ignored if the class' method prevails?).

Can you explain why you are using a Module for this?  Maybe instead you'd want to define a class and just contain an instance of it (composition rather than inheritance) in the class that uses it?

Comment: The application is a cli tool. The Settings module parses the commandline options and provides them to the application. It is not inherited or included in other classes/modules. It's just required.

Comment: I think the module approach you're using adds *way* more complexity than is necessary.  You may be able to use an `OpenStruct` for this.  Check it out at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html.  I use this all the time for command line options.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't override `=` in Ruby, and it's considered dangerous to override these types of operators. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058918/1521117) for more details.

However, this exact use case is well handled by ruby. You have two options:

```
def user= (some_object)
   @_settings = {user: some_object}
end
```

or make user an attribute of `Setting` and use `attr_accessor`

```
module Settings
  attr_accessor :user
  def new(user)
    @user = user
  end
end
```

You're almost there with `attr_reader` it is half of `attr_accessor` with the other half being `attr_writer`. Check out this other SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)